# Plotly Distplot subplots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, distribution

I am trying to write a for loop that for distplot subplots.
I have a dataframe with many columns of different lengths. (not including the NaN values)

```
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=len(assets), cols=1,
    y_title = 'Hourly Price Distribution')

i=1 
for col in df_all.columns:
    fig = ff.create_distplot([[df_all[[col]].dropna()]], col)
    fig.append()
    i+=1
fig.show()
```

I am trying to run a for loop for subplots for distplots and get the following error:

**PlotlyError: Oops! Your data lists or ndarrays should be the same length.**

UPDATE:
This is an example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'2012': np.random.randn(20),
           '2013': np.random.randn(20)+1})
df['2012'].iloc[0] = np.nan
fig = ff.create_distplot([df[c].dropna() for c in df.columns],
df.columns,show_hist=False,show_rug=False)
fig.show()
```

I would like to plot each distribution in a different subplot.

Thank you.

Comment: How did my latest suggestion work out for you?

Comment: It still hasn't worked but I'll try to tweak it a bit more. I routed to just plot every graph alone. 
Thanks for you help though.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update: Distribution plots

Calculating the correct values is probably both quicker and more elegant using `numpy`. But I often build parts of my graphs using one plotly approach(figure factory, plotly express) and then use them with other elements of the plotly library (plotly.graph_objects) to get what I want. The complete snippet below shows you how to do just that in order to build a `go` based `subplot` with elements from `ff.create_distplot`. I'd be happy to give further explanations if the following suggestion suits your needs.

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({'2012': np.random.randn(20),
           '2013': np.random.randn(20)+1})
df['2012'].iloc[0] = np.nan

df = df.reset_index()
dfm = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['index'], value_vars=df.columns[1:])
dfm = dfm.dropna()

dfm.rename(columns={'variable':'year'}, inplace = True)
cols = dfm.year.unique()
nrows = len(cols)

fig = make_subplots(rows=nrows, cols=1)

for r, col in enumerate(cols, 1):
    dfs = dfm[dfm['year']==col]
    fx1 = ff.create_distplot([dfs['value'].values], ['distplot'],curve_type='kde')
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                                x= fx1.data[1]['x'],
                                y =fx1.data[1]['y'],
                              ), row = r, col = 1)

fig.show()
```

---

#### First suggestion

---

You should:

**1.** Restructure your data with `pd.melt(df, id_vars=['index'], value_vars=df.columns[1:])`,

**2.** and the use the occuring column `'variable'` to build subplots for each `year` through the `facet_row` argument to get this:

[image]

In the complete snippet below you'll see that I've changed `'variable'` to `'year'` in order to make the plot more intuitive. There's one particularly convenient side-effect with this approach, namely that running `dfm.dropna()` will remove the `na` value for `2012` ***only***. If you were to do the same thing on your original dataframe, the corresponding value in the same row for `2013` would also be removed.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'2012': np.random.randn(20),
           '2013': np.random.randn(20)+1})
df['2012'].iloc[0] = np.nan

df = df.reset_index()
dfm = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['index'], value_vars=df.columns[1:])
dfm = dfm.dropna()

dfm.rename(columns={'variable':'year'}, inplace = True)
fig = px.histogram(dfm, x="value",
                   facet_row = 'year')
fig.show()
```

Comment: I would like to plot the density plot rather than the histogram. As far as I can tell from my searches, Plotly Express does not have a density plot, but rather it is part of the Figure Factory. I tried to use the create_distplot in your code, but it did not work.

Comment: @MathMan99 I see... I'll take another look when I find the time.

Comment: Any updates? Also note that the DataFrame has multiple columns of different lengths.

Comment: Maybe tomorrow. Feel free to remind me again.